# How to do contrast stretching in opencv or numpy?

Tags: python, opencv, numpy, image-processing, contrast

I'm trying to stretch the contrast of an opencv3 / numpy.ndarray picture in my Python 3 application.

I found the normalize method, but that seems to do the opposite, pushing 1 to 255 in the range 10 to 11 for example.
In numpy i found nothing easy, but in opencv i came across the [`convertScaleAbs` function](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#convertscaleabs).
I gave it

```
alpha=255 / (upper_boundary - lower_boundary)
```

as scaling and

```
beta=(- (lower_boundary * (255 / (upper_boundary - lower_boundary)))
```

as delta, but that is producing strange results where dark parts get extremely light despite entering e.g. 10 and 250.

I'm not sure whether my maths is correct or not.
I also saw this formula `newValue = 255 * (oldValue - minValue)/(maxValue - minValue)` in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15372807/contrast-stretching-in-local-regions-of-an-image), but I cant apply that to the scale and delta concept of the `convertScaleAbs` function, right?

Edit:
I also tried the `normalize` opencv function with `alpha=lower_boundary`, `beta=upper_boundary` `and norm_type=cv2.NORM_MINMAX`, the result is I can enter numbers between 0 and 255 but the result image only has these brightness values and the contrast is less not stretched!

Here is a minimal complete verifiable example:

```
import cv2
image = cv2.imread("Tux.png")
cv2.normalize(image, image, alpha=20, beta=200, norm_type=cv2.NORM_MINMAX)
cv2.namedWindow("TestWindow", cv2.WINDOW_AUTOSIZE)
cv2.imshow("Test", image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

I'm thankful for any hints on what easy function I may have overlooked or what I could use to do this more easily (manually)!

Comment: have a look a look at `cv::normalize`, with parameter `NORM_MINMAX`. Your last formula is ok, too.

Comment: @Miki thanks, i already tried that, see my edit for the problems.

Comment: check minimum and maximum values in your image. If they are not in [0,255] you have some problem. If your original values are in [0, 65K], you need to divide them by 256 before applying `numpy.uint8(...)`

Comment: the original values are between 0 and 255 AND the format IS uint8 already... what could be the problem?

Comment: You should post an [mcve]. It's hard to tell without seeing the code that is causing the problem with your image.

Comment: Sorry, thats right of course! Here and see edit:
`import cv2
image = cv2.imread("Tux.png")
cv2.normalize(image, image, alpha=20, beta=200)
cv2.namedWindow("TestWindow", cv2.WINDOW_AUTOSIZE)
cv2.imshow("Test", image)
cv2.waitKey(0)`

Comment: Of course I meant with norm_type=cv2.NORM_MINMAX, the result is I can enter numbers between 0 and 255 but the result image only has these brightness values and the contrast is less not stretched

Comment: you can try out [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24341114/simple-illumination-correction-in-images-opencv-c/39744436#39744436) given in my answer. It is written in python.